# Understanding Spring's Authentication-object and the context of its creation

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I am trying to get a grasp of Spring-Security and I currently have some trouble in understanding the Authentication-Object/Interface that has yet to be solved by the tutorials I found. So I would be thankful for clarification on the following aspects:

1. Concerning the interface itself:

   1.1 Is it common to create an own implementation of the Authentication-Interface? 
   1.2 Would that be the place to implement a custom form of credentials?
2. I have seen lots of examples that implement custom AuthenticationProvider but:

   2.1. where does the authenticate method get its Authentication parameter from? (I assume if I specify out of the box form-login in my config, this is the origin, but if I don't?)
   2.2 Is it possible to provide my own source of Authentication-Objects to be used by a custom AuthenticationProvider?

Maybe I can better explain the last two bits by an example.
Say I want to provide authentication via a triplet of information like username, password and the knowledge of the last two words of a poem that I give the first sentence of. So in this case my credentials would be extended from the usual user/pw scenario. Further I might want to have post-requests of a certain form as source for these credentials.

I hope this is not to vague. If I can do something to refine my question, tell me and I will try.

Comment: This is a very loaded question and would be tough to give an unbiased answer. I did my best explaining what the possibilities are, but feel free to leave comments in case I didn't answer your question(s). Integration tests and the debugger becomes your best friend for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. It's possible to define a custom Authentication object given that you satisfy the contact specified by the interface. Although given your use case, extending `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken` may be more in line with what you are trying to achieve.
2. The `.authenticate(Authentication a)` is called from the `ProviderManger` (a default implementation for `AuthenticationManager`. So when creating a custom `AuthenticationProvider` be sure to register it with the `AuthenticationManager`.

It is possible to provide your own source of Authentication objects. You can do this by setting up a filter.

You can peek at the default spring filter for form logins `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter` since that would be closes to your use case.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, that brought me on the right track to some point! I hope the following sounds not too stupid; firstly: with registering my custom AuthenticationProvider, do you mean inside my Config, like here in 5.1 for example https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-multiple-auth-providers or are you implying it would be good to provide my own AuthenticationManager-implementation? Second: I peeked inside the source-code of UserPasswordAAuthenticationFilter and its superclass AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter ( I fear I have to make several comments).

Comment: As I understand I would have to specify the destination from where I want to intercept requests with this filter which is ".../login" in U.P.A.Filter, I require those to be done by POST (constructor), correct? I suppose I will have to register this filter somehow to take effect instead of default so my first question: how is that done with best practice :)? Second: UPAFilter draws information from request-parameters as far as I see; the documentation of HttpServletRequest implies I can do it in a similar way with headers, correct?

Comment: (just saw they test for POST inside attemptAuthentication, my mistake)

Comment: Looking through the tests for spring-security and spring-security-oauth github project also provide some good resources in terms of configurations. The oauth project in particular (although may be slightly different in nature... but would probably send you in the right direction. https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-oauth/tree/master/tests/annotation/custom-authentication

Comment: Didn't help me to get further so far but I don't want to steal more of your time, so I will accept you answer as it send me a lot further then I was before and my question was after all very broad. I should probably split up what questions derived from the progress. So, thank you again!

Comment: Can you link your question?

Comment: After playing around a little bit I now posted a follow-up question; if you are willing to have a look I would appreciate that: https://stackoverflow.com/q/51986766/6294605