# Spring Security getAuthenticationManager() returns null within custom filter

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I am trying to implement a very simple example of customized authentication process in Spring to get a better understanding of the concept.

I thought i had everything in place now but sending a request to test what I implemented results in a NullPointerException which can be tracked down to
*this.getAuthenticationManager()* returning null in my custom filter. But I don't understand why. The very similar existing question didn't really help me unfortunately. So I would be thankful for help; here are the most relevant classes I think, feel free to ask if any more is needed.

*MyAuthenticationFilter* (Based on the source-code of UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter), error happens in last line of this:

```
public class MyAuthenticationFilter extends AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter {

    public MyAuthenticationFilter() {
        super(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/login", "POST"));
    }

    @Override
    public Authentication attemptAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws AuthenticationException {
            if (!request.getMethod().equals("POST")) {
                throw new AuthenticationServiceException(
                        "Authentication method not supported: " + request.getMethod());
            }

            String username = request.getParameter("username");
            String password = request.getParameter("password");
            String secondSecret = request.getParameter("secondSecret");

            if (username == null) {
                username = "";
            }

            if (password == null) {
                password = "";
            }

            username = username.trim();

            MyAuthenticationToken authRequest = new MyAuthenticationToken(username, new MyCredentials(password, secondSecret));

            return this.getAuthenticationManager().authenticate(authRequest);
    }
}
```

My config-class:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan
public class AppConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Autowired
    MyAuthenticationProvider myAuthenticationProvider;

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.authenticationProvider(myAuthenticationProvider);
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.addFilterBefore(new MyAuthenticationFilter(), BasicAuthenticationFilter.class)
                .authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/**")
                    .hasAnyRole()
                    .anyRequest()
                    .authenticated()
                    .and()
                .csrf().disable();
    }

    @Bean
    public ViewResolver viewResolver() {
        InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        viewResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/");
        viewResolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
        return viewResolver;
    }
}
```

*MyAuthenticationProvider*:

```
@Component
public class MyAuthenticationProvider implements AuthenticationProvider {
    @Override
    public Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication) throws AuthenticationException {
        MyAuthenticationToken myAuthenticationToken = (MyAuthenticationToken) authentication;
        MyCredentials credentials = (MyCredentials) myAuthenticationToken.getCredentials();
        if (credentials.getPassword().equals("sesamOeffneDich") && credentials.getSecondSecret().equals(MyAuthenticationToken.SECOND_SECRET)) {
            myAuthenticationToken.setAuthenticated(true);
            return myAuthenticationToken;
        } else {
            throw new BadCredentialsException("Bad credentials supplied!");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean supports(Class<?> authentication) {
        return MyAuthenticationToken.class.isAssignableFrom(authentication);
    }
}
```

Comment: What if you add in your constructor `setAuthenticationManager(new NoOpAuthenticationManager());` ?

Comment: I think OP wants to have his `authenticate` honored.

Comment: Added an answer, hopefully it's not too dense

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Why you're seeing a NullPointerException**

You're seeing a `NullPointerException` because you do not have an `AuthenticationManager` wired into your filter. According to the javadocs for `AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter`

> The filter requires that you set the authenticationManager property. An AuthenticationManager is required to process the authentication request tokens created by implementing classes

This being the case, I do scratch my head as to why the `authenticationManager` did not make the cut for a constructor argument for this abstract filter. I would recommend enforcing this in your constructor for your custom filter.

```
public MyAuthenticationFilter(AuthenticationManager authenticationManager) {
    super(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/login", "POST"));
    this.setAuthenticationManager(authenticationManager);
}
```

**AuthenticationManager or the AuthenticationProvider**

```
@Override
protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.authenticationProvider(myAuthenticationProvider);
}
```

The `AuthenticationManagerBuilder` will create a `ProviderManager (an AuthenticationManager)`.

The `ProviderManager` is a collection of `AuthenticationProvider` and will attempt to `authenticate()` with every `AuthenticationProvider` that it manages. (This is where `public boolean supports(Class<?> authentication)` is extremely important in the`AuthenticationProvider` contract)

In your configuration, you have created an `ProviderManager` containing just your custom `Authentication Provider`

**Cool. Now where is my AuthenticationManager?**

It is possible to grab the `AuthenticationManager` built by the `configure()` method by  `this.authenticationManager()` in the `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter`

```
@Bean
public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager throws Exception() {
    this.authenticationManager();
}
```

**Recommendations**

Creating your own `ProviderManager` does have it's benefits as it would be explicit and within your control.

```
@Bean
public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager() {
    return new ProviderManager(Arrays.asList(myAuthenticationProvider));
}
```

This will let you be flexible with the placement of your `AuthenticationManager` bean and avoid:

- Potential cyclic dependency issues in your bean configurations
- Bubbling up the checked `Exception` as a result of calling `this.authenticationManager()`

**Putting it all Together**

```
...
public class AppConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Autowired
    MyAuthenticationProvider myAuthenticationProvider;

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.addFilterBefore(new MyAuthenticationFilter(authenticationManager()), BasicAuthenticationFilter.class)
        ...
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager() {
        return new ProviderManager(Arrays.asList(myAuthenticationProvider));
    }
}
```

Comment: Additional reference point: [AuthenticationManager vs AuthenticationProvider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2323377/spring-security-authenticationmanager-vs-authenticationprovider)

Comment: Many thanks! I obviously didn't pay enough attention when reading the doc, but still your answer was probably necessary as I wouldn't have know the proper place to put everything together. As I see in the doc, ProviderManager is the only implementation for AuthenticationManager; would it make sense for my example to write my own implementation of AuthenticationManager or is it rather unusual? I am btw always thankful for additional recommendations as you wrote; it helps to establish a better contextual knowledge, so kudos for that.

Comment: Considering that you only have one `AuthenticationProvider`, you do have the option of providing an implementation of an AuthenticationManager. The `ProviderManager` is to work through different strategies

Comment: I see, doesn't seem overly necessary though; tank you!

Answer (score 2):

You should set the authentication manager to your filter.
You can do that adding this method to your configuration class

```
 @Bean 
    public MyAuthenticationFilter myAuthenticationFilter() {
        MyAuthenticationFilter res = new MyAuthenticationFilter();
        try {
            res.setAuthenticationManager(authenticationManagerBean());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return res;
    }
```

and modifying the configure method with

`http.addFilterBefore(myAuthenticationFilter(), BasicAuthenticationFilter.class).`...

Answer (score 2):

in my case nothing helped except this:

```
public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager() {
    return new ProviderManager(Arrays.asList(tokenAuthenticationProvider, 
                                             apiKeyAuthenticationProvider));
}
```